# Copy links from mysql field to another field

Tags: mysql, copying

I can't figure out whether it is possible to copy links from 1 mysql field to another?

In the first field there is some text with a simple URL at the end: `<a target="_blank" href="http://www.link.com/sdsdg">Anchor</a>`

So how can I separate each link from other text and copy that link into another mysql field?

Thank you very much. : )

Comment: In mysql, you're stuck with string operations. MySQL does **NOT** support DOM-type operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql has lots of string manipulation function [See here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

You can use these functions in a query for example: ( very simple example )

```
UPDATE table SET new_field = SUBSTRING(old_field, INSTR(old_field, '<a'), INSTR(old_field, '</a>') ) WHERE id = 10;
```

So with the use of SUBSTRING and INSTR and maybe a few others you can develop a query to do the job.